# specify the environment variable...bash, how to do

Tags: 14.04, bash, .profile, github

I downloaded software 'github SADIT' and in there it was mentioned to specify the environment variable .... in bash i.e. following

[image]

so  there mentioned something to open `.profile`
and to do something. I don't know that much about bash and .profile but open file by `nano\.profile` and add last line shown in below picture

[image]

then try to run software by given command i.e. `./cmdsadit -h` but then it was shown following

```
controllab@controllab-H81M-S1:~$ cd sadit
controllab@controllab-H81M-S1:~/sadit$ ./cmdsadit -h
Please set <SADIT_ROOT> variable in bash.
controllab@controllab-H81M-S1:~/sadit$
```

then I use command `nano bash` and copy paste total shown in image 1, but then also it was showing

```
controllab@controllab-H81M-S1:~$ cd sadit
controllab@controllab-H81M-S1:~/sadit$ ./cmdsadit -h
Please set <SADIT_ROOT> variable in bash.
controllab@controllab-H81M-S1:~/sadit$
```

what to do

Comment: You just need to enter `source ~/.profile` or log out and back in

Answer (score 1):

use **export** command

example:

```
user$ export SADIT_ROOT='/home/sadit'
user$ echo $SADIT_ROOT
/home/sadit
```